# Task scheduling

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

A simple design for task scheduling using the following classes/interfaces.

```
/// <summary>
///     Represents an executable action.
/// </summary>
public interface IExecutableTask {
    Task ExecuteAsync();
}

/// <summary>
///     A task which can be planned for execution.
/// </summary>
public interface IPlannedTask : IExecutableTask {
    TimeSpan? GetExecutionDelay( DateTimeOffset? lastExecutedAt );
    DateTimeOffset? GetExecutionTime( DateTimeOffset? lastExecutedAt );
}

/// <summary>
///     A task which can be scheduled to run periodically.
/// </summary>
public interface IPeriodicTask : IPlannedTask {
    TimeSpan Frequency { get; }
}

/// <summary>
///     A task which can be planned to run at specific times of the day.
/// </summary>
public interface IScheduledTask : IPlannedTask {
    IReadOnlyList<TimeSpan> ExecutionTimes { get; }
}
```

And as for the execution mechanism

```
public class PlannedTaskRegistration {
    public PlannedTaskRegistration( IPlannedTask task, Timer timer ) {
        Task = task;
        Timer = timer;
    }
    public IPlannedTask Task { get; set; }
    public Timer Timer { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LastExecutedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? NextExecutionAt { get; set; }
    public bool IsExecuting { get; set; }
}

public class TaskManager {
    private readonly List<PlannedTaskRegistration> _registrations = new List<PlannedTaskRegistration>();
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    public bool IsEnabled { get; private set; }

    public void Add( IPlannedTask task ) {
        var registration = new PlannedTaskRegistration(task, null!);
        var timer = new Timer(TimerTick, registration, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
        registration.Timer = timer;

        lock( _lock ) {
            _registrations.Add(registration);
            RescheduleTask(registration, false);
        }
    }
    public void Start() {
        lock( _lock ) {
            if( IsEnabled ) { return; }
            IsEnabled = true;
            foreach( var registration in _registrations.ToList() ) {
                RescheduleTask(registration, false);
            }
        }
    }
    public void Stop() {
        lock( _lock ) {
            if( !IsEnabled ) { return; }
            IsEnabled = false;
            foreach( var registration in _registrations ) {
                RescheduleTask(registration, false);
            }
        }
    }
    private async void TimerTick( object state ) {
        var registration = (PlannedTaskRegistration)state;
        try {
            lock( registration ) {
                if( registration.IsExecuting ) { return; }
                registration.IsExecuting = true;
            }
            registration.Timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            await registration.Task.ExecuteAsync();
        } catch {
            // catch/log exceptions
        } finally {
            // reschedule the task
            lock( _lock ) {
                RescheduleTask(registration, true);
            }
        }
    }

    private void RescheduleTask( PlannedTaskRegistration registration, bool isPostExecutionCall ) {
        lock( registration ) {
            if( registration.IsExecuting && !isPostExecutionCall ) {
                // the task is executing right now, do not reschedule
                return;
            }

            var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            if( isPostExecutionCall ) {
                registration.LastExecutedAt = now;
            }

            if( IsEnabled ) {
                var executionDelay = registration.Task.GetExecutionDelay(now);
                if( executionDelay is null ) {
                    _registrations.Remove(registration);
                } else {
                    registration.NextExecutionAt = now.Add(executionDelay.Value);
                    registration.Timer.Change(executionDelay.Value, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
                    registration.IsExecuting = false;
                }
            } else {
                registration.NextExecutionAt = null;
                registration.Timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This design allows the planning of two types of tasks that appear in the system

- Periodic tasks that should execute with a given frequency, no matter the time of day (e.g. deferred mail sending)
- Scheduled tasks that should execute at certain times of the day (e.g. system clean-ups at 3 am)

Few of my observations/concerns

1. I `lock` the whole collection processing, but I believe the time spent in the locked region is not excessive, plus I remove elements from the list. Lastly, I think it's very plausible given the use case for the class tip-toeing around locks could worsen performance (not too many tasks executing and their intersections are improbable).
2. I think this design should protect me from unwanted multi-executions by, e.g. rapidly starting/stopping the `TaskManager`.
3. I'm aware that stopping/starting the `TaskManager` while a task is running won't restart the task immediately and will reschedule it according to the "previous" schedule once it's done.

Can you spot any bugs/possible edge-case unwanted behaviours? Any other flaws, such as unclear naming, etc.?